# Error 0xC0000005 Occurs when Debugging, but Program and Variables work and are assigned successfully when stepping through

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, struct

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using namespace std;

class dataLine
{

double time;
    int id;
    int inten;
    int cov;
    int type;

    void copyDataLine(dataLine *dat2)
    {
        time = dat2->time;
        /*inten = dat2->inten;
        cov = dat2->cov;
        type = dat2->type;*/
        return;
    }
};

class findLines
{
private:
    int lines;
    ifstream datFile;
    string line;
public:
    int countLines()
    {
        lines = 0;
        datFile.open("precipitation.txt");
        if (datFile.good())

        {
            while (!datFile.eof())
            {
                getline(datFile, line);
                lines++;
            }

        }
        return lines;
    }
};

void readData(dataLine *datLine_one[], dataLine *datLine_two[], dataLine *datLine_three[], dataLine *datLine_four[])
{
    fstream datFile;
    dataLine *datLine = new dataLine;;
    *datLine = dataLine();
    datFile.open("precipitation.txt");
    int count[]{ 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0 };

    while (!datFile.eof())
    {
        datFile >> datLine->time;
        datFile >> datLine->id;
        datFile >> datLine->inten;
        datFile >> datLine->cov;
        datFile >> datLine->type;
        if (datLine->id == 1)
        {
            datLine_one[count[1]]->copyDataLine(datLine);
            count[1]++;
        }
        /*else if (datLine->id == 2)
        {
            datLine_two[count[2]]->copyDataLine(datLine);
            count[2]++;
        }*/
        /*if (datLine->id == 3)
        {
            copyDataLine(datLine_three[count[3]], datLine);
            count[3]++;
        }
        if (datLine->id == 4)
        {
            copyDataLine(datLine_four[count[4]], datLine);
            count[4]++;
        }*/


    }


    return;
}


int main()
{
    findLines precip;
    int lineNum = precip.countLines();
    int datNum = lineNum / 4;

    dataLine *datLine_1 = new dataLine[datNum];
    dataLine *datLine_2 = new dataLine[datNum];
    dataLine *datLine_3 = new dataLine[datNum];
    dataLine *datLine_4 = new dataLine[datNum];

    readData(&datLine_1, &datLine_2, &datLine_3, &datLine_4);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This code is set to read in data from a file, and store it in different arrays based on the IDs of the data (five columns and 33317 rows). The variables are shown to be assigned successfully if I step through the code in Visual Studio, but when I try to debug it, an exception occurs when the copyDataLine function is called.

Comment: At the very least you should be pointing out on which line the crash/error occurs. Though this code looks pretty suspicious and most likely has some *undefined behavior* somewhere in there (and also a lot of memory leaks)

Comment: `main()` dynamically allocates arrays with `4` elements.   The file has `13317` rows, so the reading code will try to treat that array of `4` elements as if it has `13317` elements.

Comment: [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) Also, you're not freeing anything you new up. And `dataLine *datLine = new dataLine;;
    *datLine = dataLine();` is pointless because it was already default-constructed.

Comment: Opening the file in `readData` most likely fails. It has already been opened in `findLines::countLines`, and never closed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the `readData` function, the variables `datLine_one` etc. are not arrays of pointers. It is a pointer to an array (or really a pointer to a pointer variable).

You can solve your problem very easily by *not* passing the addresses to the pointer variables in the `main` function, and not declaring the arguments as pointers to pointers.

So something like this instead:

```
void readData(dataLine *datLine_one, dataLine *datLine_two, dataLine *datLine_three, dataLine *datLine_four)
{
    ...
    datLine_one[count[1]].copyDataLine(datLine);
    ...
}

int main()
{
    ...
    readData(datLine_1, datLine_2, datLine_3, datLine_4);
    ...
}
```